# Why is the Ubuntu partition seen as unallocated space after Windows 8 upgrade?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 as dual-boot. Today I decided to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8 on the other partition. I read on some forums that I would most likely need a liveUSB to repair grub after upgrading Windows, so I could boot into Ubuntu again. After installing Windows, I used the live-cd to repair Boot-manager using the program "boot-repair".

URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5609860/

However I still cannot get access to Ubuntu and furthermore, according to GParted, the partition with Ubuntu 12.04 is seen as unallocated space (!). Did I do something wrong, did I somehow remove Ubuntu? Since I have not done any data back up before Windows upgrade, I want to access to Ubuntu, without having to re-install it. Could someone look at my url of boot-repair, and give me suggestions what I could do?

PS: I have used testdisk program, but it fails to recognize actual size of Ubuntu partition and thus I didn't proceed.

Comment: maybe windows cant read the disk because it is formatted in a different type like ext4?
because windows says the same to me

Comment: True that Windows can not read ext4 partition but I have used LiveUSB (Ubuntu) and still it recognize that partition as unallocated. Even, Gparted and testdisk both fail to recognize it. But I am pretty much sure that the files are intact. Windows 8 has done something wrong with the boot manger and so I lost the access to Ubuntu on my laptop.